Why is $f:\#_A\mapsto \#[A(^\circ\#_A)]$ computable?
In a proof of the Dagional Lemma, Wikipedia claims that the function
$$f:n\mapsto 
\begin{cases}
\#[A(^\circ\#_A)] & \text{ if $n = \#_A$ for some sentence $A$} \\
0 & \text{ otherwise} 
\end{cases}
$$
is computable, where $\#_A$ is the Gödel number of $A$ and $^\circ n$ is the numeral of $n\in\mathbb{N}$. How can we show that $f$ is computable?

Intuitively, I wish to do the following:

Assume the function $g:A\mapsto \#_A$ is computable, which is to mean there is a Turing machine with alphabet $\{0, 1\}$ together with the collection of logical and non-logical symbols of the $L$, if started on the left-most symbol of a formula on an otherwise empty string, will halt on the left-most $1$ of a string of $\#_A$ $1$s.

The inverse of $g$ is computable, which is to say there is there is a Turing machine, with the same alphabet as before, such that, when started on the left-most $1$ of a string of $n$ $1$s, will halt in an empty string if $n$ is not the Gödel number of any formula, and otherwise will halt on the left-most symbol of the formula $n = \#_A$ on an otherwise empty string.


From these two assumptions, I think I could show that $f$ is computable. However, the alphabet of a Turing machine should be finite, while the collection of logical and non-logical symbols is infinite.

You can encode infinitely many symbols ${x_i}_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ using a binary alphabet by saying that you use $01^i0$ in place of the $x_i$. In other words, TMs with binary or countable alphabets are equivalent from the computability point of view.
